# Is there a term for grammatical mistakes as a result of trying too hard?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypercorrection

Today, I learned the term [*hyperforeignism*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperforeignism) after writing that I was drinking a *latté* and then stopping to wonder why I was putting a diacritical mark on the "e".

This reminded me of other language mistakes that occur *more frequently* when people are *actively trying to make fewer language mistakes*, such as:

- Every "----- and me" becomes "----- and I"
- Scattering "myself" throughout one's speech
- "whom" overuse

These mistakes tend to reveal "I'm talking to an authority figure" or "I'm talking to a group that I may not be qualified to be speaking to".

Is there a term for this phenomenon?

Comment: Well, it is already answered as Hypercorrection, but you should also check out the About page about this : http://grammar.about.com/od/fh/g/hpercorrterm.htm

Comment: There is also "hypocorrection". In that old *We Are The World* Live Aid song, the line *... saving our own lives* is paired with *... just you and me*. Here is where *I* **can** be used in place of *me*! Furthermore, it **rhymes** better with *lives*. Doh?

Comment: @Kaz, are you sure that's hypocorrection rather than just an home-dialect-based decision that *me* was better? For anyone not following, btw, *hypocorrection* is a kinda opposite thing to hypercorrection where you sorta use slangy or dialecty or, eh, not really right talk so that while you lose some like eloquence you avoid appearing like a snobby git, 'cos that's how you roll. While hypercorrection may (among other motives) come from attempting speech that would be more privileged, hypocorrection attempts speech that would often be less privileged, for a variety of motives.

Comment: And for that matter, there's another sense of both *hypercorrection* and *hypocorrection* in terms of how we fill in blanks (or fail to) when we have a difficulty in correctly perceiving the message conveyed.

Comment: This question has garnered some hyperresponsivity.

Comment: You should hypercorrect the spelling of "througout". :-) It won't let me fix a one-character error.

Comment: I wonder if *hyperforeignism* could be applied to when cooks think simple foreign foods should be complicated and "fancy", and ruin them.

Comment: A closely related idea is ["smelling of the lamp"](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-sme1.htm)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

*Hypercorrection*

It can even influence a language: *Fetus* is the original Latin term, but it got "fixed" to *foetus* or *fœtus* both in how people wrote Latin, and also in languages that had a term derived from it so now *foetus* is sometimes found in English, Dutch and German and also *fötus* in German; all based on people "fixing" what wasn't broken.

In between personal hypercorrection and something introducing a new spelling that became common across four different languages, are myths like "the passive voice should be avoided", "don't start a sentence with a conjunction", "don't start a sentence with *however*", "don't split infinitives", "don't split any verb form", "don't end a sentence with a preposition", "don't use the genitive of an noun that represents a non-living thing", "don't use *like* as a conjunctive". Here not only has someone got a bizarre notion into their heads about what is correct, but the "rule" has ended up being actively taught.

Often it's combined with an incorrect understanding of its own terms, as in this notorious example:
[image: non-passive passives]
[source](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/grammar/passives.html)

Not only is this teacher enforcing an imaginary rule, but of the 10 cases marked as "P.V.", only three are in the passive voice. Of those 3, only one seems like it could be rewritten into something that didn't weaken it (and that one still wouldn't actually improve). One actual use of the passive voice isn't marked as such.

In theory, such a "rule" could become so popular, that it became a real rule just by dominating the thinking of those who spoke the language. Many though are actually impossible to follow consistently, or just too at odds with common literate use, to ever reach that point.

Comment: This answer is highly misleading (except for the hypercorrection part that actually answered the question). The example, however, clearly demonstrates passive voice. Words such as were, was, is, that, and other passive verbs should be avoided in great writing. Action verbs should replace these words because they force the writer to be more specific and make the writing clearer and more interesting to read.

Comment: @nathanhayfield: There's a huge difference between "passive voice" and "passive verbs".

Comment: I beg to differ. If a difference exists, then it must be slight.

Comment: @nathanhayfield, how is *that* a verb? What does choice of verb have to do with choice of voice?

Comment: When did I state "that" is a verb? Passive choices in writing always result in a passive voice. It matters not what part of the writing looks passive.

Comment: @nathanhayfield 24mins ago when you wrote, "Words such as were, was, is, that, and other passive verbs". Anyway, "I got stabbed in the my left eye." is entirely in the passive voice. Why do you think it's weaker than "Somebody stabbed me in my left eye"? I favour the former for losing the irrelevant "somebody".

Comment: I don't think it's weaker. But an improved version would be 
"An ugly old man sliced through my left eye with a pair of dull scissors." Also I said "Words such as" and then included other passive verbs in with the other words. You may have inferred from that, that 'that' was a verb but that would be a poor assumption. (Yay three terrible words in a row)

Comment: Maybe I don't know who did it, or what with; having been stabbed in the eye can make you a poor witness to details. Anyway, if you don't think my first example weaker than my second, that would mean you agree that the passive voice need not be weaker than the active, since the first is in the passive voice and the second in the active.

Comment: I don't understand the red mark on *mentions*.  None of that stuff is passive voice. For example, "was using" is a progressive past, not passive. "I used it once" versus "I was using that for a while". What is passive voice is "I was used by him" (as opposed to the active voice "He used me"). This paper grader is a pitiful idiot of a teacher or teaching assistant.

Comment: @Kaz, if you look carefully, three of them are indeed in the passive voice, while one thing not marked as passive is indeed. But that was entirely my point—not only are they applying a bogus "zombie rule", they aren't even applying it correctly by their own standards.

Comment: @JAM If I recall correctly, the "fix" of *fetus* to *fœtus* happened in the 16th C. Anyway, there are some others where the Latin was always *e* but it got "fixed" to *æ* or *œ* or double-sins where *æ* got contracted to *e* then "fixed" to *œ* or vice versa. I think foetus was the only one to become as common as it did, but you can, for example find *et caetera*, *et coetera*, *et cœtera* and *et cætera* all being used within a variety of European languages where neither the Latin nor the rules of that language justify it.

Comment: Yes, for instance "X was obviously interested in doing so" could be phrased as "Doing so obviously interested X, ..."

Comment: @Kaz you could, but it's still more using "obviously interested in doing so" as an adjectival phrase than as a verb in the passive voice. Have you followed the link I have with the image? I've a feeling you'll appreciate that, and even more so some of the blog posts it links to.

Comment: @JAM LOL. But surely the thing that makes it obvious that I meant recall my understand of the history rather than recall the event, is that my engaging in a massive flame-war over it isn't part of the historical record ;)

Answer (score 13):

Hypercorrection.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercorrection) has:

> In linguistics or usage, hypercorrection is a non-standard usage that results from the over-application of a perceived rule of grammar or a usage prescription. A speaker or writer who produces a hypercorrection generally believes that the form is correct through misunderstanding of these rules, often combined with a desire to seem formal or educated.
>
> Linguistic hypercorrection occurs when a real or imagined grammatical rule is applied in an inappropriate context, so that an attempt to be "correct" leads to an incorrect result.
>
> Hypercorrection is sometimes found among speakers of less prestigious language varieties who produce forms associated with high-prestige varieties, even in situations where speakers of those varieties would not. Some commentators call such production hyperurbanism.

Answer (score 9):

I've seen this kind of mistake referred to on this very site as a [hypercorrection](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hypercorrection):

> The use of a nonstandard form due to a belief that it is more formal
>   or more correct than the corresponding standard form.

Answer (score 1):

You've already got your answer, but a related term is "superstandard" or "supercorrect" speech which is perceived by most people as going beyond the requirements of normal language use but not necessarily going so far as to break grammatical rules.

From http://www.linguistics.ucsb.edu/faculty/bucholtz/articles/MB_JLA2001.pdf:

> A linguistic superstandard is a variety that surpasses the
>   prescriptive norm established by the standard.

and,

> I use the terms superstandard and supercorrect to distinguish between true hypercorrect language use (that is, use that violates a rule of descriptive grammar) and
>   strict adherence to prescriptive grammatical rules accompanied by the use of other
>   formal language features. As discussed below, however, hypercorrection is often
>   part of superstandard English.

Answer (score 0):

[Muphry's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muphry%27s_law) describes a more specific case of this phenomenon - the tendency for people to make mistakes when criticising other people's proofreading.

Comment: Though there's also the fun inverse: If someone is being really nasty in stating uninvited criticisms of someone's speech or writing, they will always give you ample opportunity to turn the tables on them.