# The proper term for a person who uses words incorrectly

Tags: word-usage, pejorative-language

What is the proper term for a person who uses words incorrectly, hoping to impress
 others?

Comment: ummm, if they use the words incorrectly, how is that impressing others?

Comment: "trying too hard"?

Comment: Related, but not a complete match is http://english.stackexchange.com/q/102443/15770 because attempting to impress is a common reason for being hypercorrect.

Comment: @KristinaLopez might want to try that again, hah

Answer (score 3):

[Pretentious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pretentious) is a good word to describe such a person. I don't know of a word that specifically refers to using words in this way. You could say "verbally pretentious".

Answer (score 3):

wikipedia has [bushism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bushism), but I think you are looking for something like

The person suffers from

- [Malapropism](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/malapropism), or
- [Catachresis](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catachresis)

Comment: Definitely Bushism!

Answer (score 2):

If the speaker were female, *Mrs. Malaprop* was a fictional character who used words incorrectly and the source of the word [malapropism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism). If the speaker were male, calling him *Dogberry* is a less known, but parallel fictional character, who used malapropisms.

It seems that both Mrs. Malaprop and Dogberry were trying to impress their hearers, but came up with a wrong word with humorous effect.

> Anyone engaging in illegal financial transactions will be caught and persecuted.

(He meant *prosecuted*.) -George W. Bush, Washington, D.C., Sept. 19, 2008

> The reforms we seek would bring greater competition, choice, savings
>   and inefficiencies to our health care system.

(He probably meant *efficiencies*. This is more of a Freudian Slip, and less a malapropism.) —Barack Obama, in remarks after a health care roundtable with physicians, nurses and health care providers, Washington, D.C., July 20, 2009

Answer (score 0):

How about *pseudo-intellectual*?